# Не срабатывает функция strstr()

Tags: c++

```
void SearchWord(MyString *_strings, int _number)
{
char *word = new char[80];
char *istr;
char *word2;
cout << "\nВведите слово для поиска в строке: ";
cin >> word;
for (int i = 0; i < _number; i++) {
    word2 = _strings[i].getString();
    istr = strstr(word, word2);
    if (istr != NULL) {
        cout << "В объекте strings[" << i << "] " << "поле String содержится слово ";
        _strings[i].showString();
    }
}
delete[] word;
 }
```

Функция поиска слова в строке не даёт результат.
 [image: В отладчике]

Comment: Переставьте местами параметры `word` и `word2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Читаем описание функции [`strstr`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strstr/):

```
const char * strstr ( const char * str1, const char * str2 );
```

> Returns a pointer to the first occurrence of `str2` in `str1`, or a null pointer if `str2` is not part of `str1`.

Т.е. ищется строка `str2` внутри `str1`.

В Вашем же случае получается, что Вы ищите строку `"Anton Logvinov"` в строке `"Anton"`, и очевидно, что не находите.

Поменяйте аргументы местами:

```
strstr(word2, word);
```

Comment: Спасибо, перепутал!

Comment: @kotelliada пожалуйста. Читайте мануалы, там много полезного :)